# Creating a PCL that targets Monodroid

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am looking at the shiny MVVMCross project, specifically the [N+1 days of MVVMCross series](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W), and I notice that @slodge creates a PCL that targets Mono for android and Monotouch (at 1:10).

I have mono for Android installed, but my VS does not give me any PCL targets apart from the standard - am I doing anything wrong?

[image: The missing options]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The situation for PCLs is changing - Xamarin are releasing official support for PCLs very soon.

In the meantime, there are quite a few blog posts around on how to get PCLs working unofficially - eg.:

- http://blogs.endjin.com/2013/05/xamarin-platform-setup-gotchas/
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

These unofficial mods have been around for over a year now - eg all the way back to http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-portable-library-tools-for.html

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Stuart - I tried googling this before posting but was drowning in noise