# xamarin support in Add Portable Class Library dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

What are the steps required to make the two items available in the Add Portable Class Library dialog?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a PCL that targets Monodroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634788/creating-a-pcl-that-targets-monodroid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer in [Creating a PCL that targets Monodroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634788/creating-a-pcl-that-targets-monodroid)

> In the meantime, there are quite a few blog posts around on how to get PCLs working unofficially - eg.:
>
> - http://blogs.endjin.com/2013/05/xamarin-platform-setup-gotchas/
> - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: thank you. although I have several other small issues to get started.