# Add xamarin.ios and xamarin.android to portable class library

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

When adding a new portable class Library project using visual studio 2012, in the add target window I can't find xamarin.ios and xamarin.android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xamarin support in Add Portable Class Library dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678066/xamarin-support-in-add-portable-class-library-dialog) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634788/creating-a-pcl-that-targets-monodroid

Comment: note that official support for this is coming "very soon" to the alpha channel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. Follow the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-3-0-6-nuget-package-installation-issue), if you hit any issues.

1. Open an explorer window to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104\SupportedFrameworks`
2. Create a new file in the folder named 'MonoTouch.xml' and put in the following content

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   > <Framework MinimumVersion="4.0" MaximumVersion="*" Profile="*" Identifier="MonoTouch" DisplayName="MonoTouch"/>
   > ```
3. Create a new file in the folder named 'MonoAndroid.xml' and put in the following content

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   > <Framework MaximumVersion="*" MinimumVersion="1.6" Profile="*" Identifier="MonoAndroid" DisplayName="Mono for Android"/>
   > ```
4. Restart Visual Studio if it is still open
5. The options for MonoTouch and Mono for Android should now be available in the PCL 
   [image]

Comment: For PCLs, you definitely can use .Net 4.0. This topic probably needs to be updated now as Visual Studio 2012/2013 and Xamarin Studio now include appropriate support for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android PCL platforms. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/