# Why do I need to 'share' code via links? Why can't I just reference my Core project via the Android project?

Tags: xamarin.android

It's tedious adding links to the Core project in each platform's project. Why do I need to do this? Why can't I just add a reference to each?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, adding links can be tedious, but the reasoning is sound. The MONO implementation of .Net does not support all of the functionality that you may get out of the full release of .Net 4.0 or 4.5. Xamarin provides a rundown of what is supported [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies). The idea is that they do their best to support the parts of .Net which would be critical and logical for a mobile release. This is the same logic that Microsoft applied towards the Silverlight release of .Net. Although linking can be a pain, it can be helpful if you need to implement platform-specific logic.

There is another alternative to file linking though. Portable Class Libraries offer much of the same features, but you can build and compile them all in one project and then reference that project. Depending on the Portable Class Library version that you implement, certain features may not be available though ([More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)). Xamarin offers a rough overview of this [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_3_-_setting_up_a_xamarin_cross_platform_solution). Information on adding Portal Class Library support can be found at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979399/add-xamarin-ios-and-xamarin-android-to-portable-class-library/16985259#16985259).